# Possible to have two prototype cells from two different arrays, without sections?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I'm having a heck of a time trying to achieve this, so any help is greatly appreciated:

- The first table is user posts, and when an item is selected, the 2nd tableview shows the selected user post, and below this, are any comments for that post, if there are any (like Facebook).
- I have two prototype cells with NO sections.
- I want to feed into the first row from one array (userPost)
- And then the 2nd prototype cell will contain any data from a separate comments array, if there are any, which will be all the rows beyond the first row.

  - Currently both prototype cells use the same custom cell class with different outlets, although I had first had two custom cell classes, but it didn't seem to work with the code examples I tried.
- I need the two separate arrays because they come from two different tables within cloudkit. And I didn't want to pull all the comments data at the same time as pulling the userPost data to display in the first tableview.

  I've found a few example questions on SO, but none have worked for my situation because they're slightly different.  And none are in swift as well.  I'd be ok with sections, but I can't get more then one section to show up in the interface builder, where I can have one prototype cell per section. And I'd really prefer to not have sections, as I don't need titles.

Anyone have any code solutions in Swift for this, in particular on how to implement the "numberOfRowsInSection" and "cellForRowAtIndexPath"?

I've tried these two examples for the "cellForRowAtIndexPath" without any luck:

```
 //  var cell: TableViewCell


  if indexPath.row == 0 {

        let cellPost = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellPost", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TableViewCell
// custom cell class

        let record = userPost[indexPath.row]

        cellPost.postDescription.text = record.description
        cellPost.userName.text = record.username


        if record.postPic != nil {

            cellPost.postPic.image = record.postPic!

        }


        cell = cellPost

       }  else  {


        let cellComment = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellComment", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TableViewCell

        let recordComment = commentResults[indexPath.row]
        // could it be that its trying to subscript 1, but there's only data at 0?

        cellComment.comment.text = recordComment.userComment
        cellComment.commentUsername.text = recordComment.username

      cell = cellComment


   }


    return cell
```

And I tried this, with no luck:

```
var identifier: String!

if indexPath.row == 0 {
   identifier == "CellPost"
} else {
   identifier == "CellComment"
}

 // then I configure the cell using the identifier as parameter.
```

And in the numberofRowsinSection I've tried:

```
return feedResults.count + commentResults.count
//OR
return commentResults.count + 1
// OR
 if commentResults.count > 0 && feedResults.count > 0 {

        return feedResults.count + commentResults.count

    } else {

        return feedResults.count
    }
```

The errors I do keep getting involve the 2nd commentResults array - either says -  "cannot index empty buffer", or "array index out of range". I only have one comment in the array at this time. Not sure if this is causing the issue.

The data is there, but it won't pull it in. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, this is possible. In numberOfRowsInSection, return the count of the comments (I assume you have those in an array) plus one (for the post). In cellForRowAtIndexPath, use an if-else clause, and return one kind of cell if indexPath.row equals zero, and dequeue the other type of cell if not.

Comment: Hi @rdelmar. I don't have the comment count in the array yet.   But I did try - commentResults.count + 1.  I think my problem is within the cellForRowAtIndexPath. But I think I tried your idea. I've updated my post to clarify and include the code examples I've tried without any luck. Thank you!

Comment: @ReneeOlson, it's not clear what information you're passing from the first table view to the second, and how you get the comments data. One thing you need to do with commentResults is access it with indexPath.row - 1 so you can access the record at index 0 (which will be the only one if you have just the one comment).

Comment: I'm passing a CKRecord into 1st tableview. I do a DB query and pass the data into a class and append into an array which is an instance of the class.  So, the first table lists all user posts, and then if someone selects one user post, it goes to a new tableview with only that post and any comments.  The comments are pulled from DB when the 2nd tableview loads, but from a different table, so they go into a different array.    I thought the else part of my if statement would cover any indexPath.row beyond 0.

Comment: Hi @rdelmar. I got it to work by doing two things....I changed the var cell type from my custom cell class to UITableviewCell!  And the other fix was your idea - indexPath.row - 1. Thanks so much!!!!

Comment: Hi @rdelmar. Strange after I changed var cell back to my custom cell, it still works now, even though yesterday only changing the indexPath.row - 1 wasn't working at first.  Strange.  I guess it was your idea and perhaps something not hooked up right.